# Pixel wide gaps between each <div> with flexbox due to pixel rounding error

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

How do I remove the black lines that seem to be caused by errors in rounding fractions of a pixel? This appears to be an issue with Chrome only, Firefox seems to be doing more intelligent rounding and renders it perfectly.

Is there an easy solution for this problem?

This is how Chrome renders it:

[image: Chrome bug]

```css
  .container {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: nowrap column;
  }
  .row {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I doubt there is—it depends on how each browser chooses to render subpixel values/dimensions. Remember that your code will call for flexbox to redistribute leftover spaces between each child evenly, which means it is very likely you will arrive at a fractional value for computed child widths.

Comment: you may try to fill the .. gap? ... with 
        `box-shadow:0 1px lightgreen` .My chrome(w7) doesn't mess up . did you play with zoom ?

Comment: just to let you know: In Chrome 47 on MacOS there are no lines - just an all green area

Comment: have you tried `margin: 0;`, or removing _any_ space between the divs (i.e. no line-breaks)?

Comment: @Johannes I think I figured out the issue. I have system-wide DPI scaling enabled (for high resolution monitors). When I disabled it (and logged in again), chrome renders it perfectly. SO this entirely looks like Chrome's fault. I guess there's nothing that can be done about this, so I'll mark it as solved?

Comment: you could add this as an answer to you own question and mark it as solved

Comment: @GCyrillus That is a clever workaround, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

you may try to fil the gap(?) with box-shadow

```css
.container {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: nowrap column;
  }
  .row {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    box-shadow:0 1px lightgreen;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good answer to the problem, but doesn't answer the question "how to fix the gap created by Chrome?". I'm having the same problem but instead of having flat-coloured background I have images with tremendous different colours and I still don't know what to do.

Comment: @enriquo you should post your own question with a snippet that shows your issue . There is some strange bugs where fix can be unexpected . Here box-shadow works for borders or plain bg, that's a quick 'n easy fix ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think I figured out the issue. I have system-wide DPI scaling enabled (for high resolution monitors). When I disabled it (and logged in again), chrome renders it perfectly (at all zoom levels). So this entirely looks like Chrome's fault. I guess there's nothing that can be done about this, so I guess I'll mark it as solved. Thanks for your help guys.