# Why is there a hairline gap / border between these block elements in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: html, css, blink

When I add a background color to a container and then stack block elements inside, there is a hairline gap visible between the elements in Chrome. No such gap exists in Firefox.

Why? And how can this be avoided without additional wrapper elements?

It's easier to see in this JS Bin: https://razor-x.jsbin.com/teqevoc/6/edit?html,css,output

```css
.main {
  background-color: black;
}

.item {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm on Chrome and see no hairline gap

Comment: @j08691 I've added an image. I'm using Chrome Version 54.0.2840.100 (64-bit).

Comment: #norepro on Chrome 56.0.2922.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit) or 54.0.2840.99 (Official Build) m (32-bit) on Windows 10.0.14393 (64-bit).

Comment: From the size of the font on your screenshot compared to the size on my screen (1080p) I am thinking that you are working on a hi-DPI screen? I cannot replicate your behaviour on Chrome on my monitor, but I have come across similar issues when testing on my Surface Pro 3. The problem has already been dealt with [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34387441/pixel-wide-gaps-between-each-div-with-flexbox-due-to-pixel-rounding-error) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397347/remove-visible-gaps-between-elements-possible-chrome-defect) but not to satisfaction imo.

Comment: DPI scaling issue?

Comment: The issue is caused by subpixel rendering in Chrome, but a good solution is not available I think.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Chromium 53.0.2785.143 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Yes I am using HiDPI screens. I'll have to test later on a different OS / resolution combination.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume you used only that CSS and HTML, that should work perfectly fine in all browsers. Maybe it's a chrome extension you have installed that adds some pixels or elements to your HTML. Try to disable all your chrome extensions (if any) and refresh.

Answer (score 0):

This happens in webkit pretty frequently. Assuming there's no other elements pushing things out of the way this can be fixed via adding

```
position:relative;
top: -1px;
```

Which is usually not noticable on browsers like firefox and fixes it up on webkit/chrome.

Comment: It's worked on my projects and it's been tested on a variety of different devices mobile and otherwise so extensions weren't causing the issue.

Comment: position:relative and top:-1px are clear what they mean. 1px gap is often not a big deal, but if you want to work pixel-perfect, then you have something not right. There are many things that can affect extra gap: line-height, vertical-align, font-size, padding, margin, min/max-height/width, display, position, etc. You name it.

Comment: `position: relative;
top: -1px;
left: -1px;
width: calc(100% + 2px);
`
worked a charm.